# UICollectionView not connecting to class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view inside of a normal view-controller, and I want to connect to a class (to configure cells i.e.). I type in the the name of the class in the identity inspector but it is not connecting to the class.

[storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBLOc.png)

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A0k8.png)

Comment: Yes I know I didn't add a prototype cell, Xcode isn't letting me set the custom class.

Comment: show your storyboard where you cannot change the class name

Comment: Added storyboard screenshot

Comment: Have you connected the storyboard to the code? Have you ctrl-dragged your `UICollectionView` into the code?

Comment: I did but the collection view is not responding. It won't let me set the custom class and it does not auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code is a subclass of a [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller) (which is a subclass of `UIViewController`), but the object in your storyboard is a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview). `UICollectionView` is different from `UICollectionViewController`, which is why XCode won't let you change the class and doesn't offer it as an option with autocomplete.

You have a couple of options to accomplish what you're attempting. You could create a container view in your storyboard and then embed your `UICollectionViewController` subclass as a child view controller.

The more standard approach, however, would be to change your code to be a subclass of `UIViewController`, give it a `UICollectionView` (not view controller) as a property, and have it conform to the [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) and [UICollectionViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource) protocols.